# How to search/filter from a list from an API?

Tags: flutter, list, api, search, filter

I have managed to load a list of cryptocurrencies from an API. This is done via the ListView.builder.

Subsequently, how does one perform a search/filter in order to select an item from the list?

By scrolling towards the end to see the last code, I have shown the code that I presumed would be able to do the job of 'search'. But I am unsure where to place this code.

Image below shows current crypto list loaded from API:

[image]

The code for the above screen is as follows:

```
class AddCryptoAssetScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddCryptoAssetScreenState createState() => _AddCryptoAssetScreenState();
}

class _AddCryptoAssetScreenState extends State<AddCryptoAssetScreen> {
  Future<List<Asset>> fetchCoin() async {
    assetList = [];
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> values = [];
      values = json.decode(response.body);
      if (values.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (values[i] != null) {
            Map<String, dynamic> map = values[i];
            assetList.add(Asset.fromJson(map));
          }
        }
        setState(() {
          assetList;
        });
      }
      return assetList;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load coins');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchCoin();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) => fetchCoin());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        builder: (_, controller) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(),
                  child: TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only()),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: assetList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return AssetCryptoCard(
                        name: assetList[index].name,
                        image: assetList[index].image,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Asset class is as follows. To derive assetList.

```
class Asset {
  String name;
  String image;
  num currentPrice;
  num priceChange24h;
  num priceChangePercentage24h;
  String symbol;

  

  Asset({
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    required this.currentPrice,
    required this.priceChange24h,
    required this.priceChangePercentage24h,
    required this.symbol,
  });

  factory Asset.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Asset(
      name: json['name'],
      symbol: json['symbol'],
      image: json['image'],
      currentPrice: json['current_price'],
      priceChange24h: json['price_change_24h'],
      priceChangePercentage24h: json['price_change_percentage_24h'],
    );
  }
}

List<Asset> assetList = [];
```

The AssetCryptoCard class is as follows.

```
class AssetCryptoCard extends StatelessWidget {
  AssetCryptoCard({
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
  });

  final String name;
  final String image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => EditAssetScreen(),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(child: Image.network(image)),
                SizedBox(),
                Text(name),
                Spacer(),
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
              ],
            ),
            Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have written the code below but unsure where is the right place to put it. Also, presumably this is the right code to do a search/filter on the list.

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> foundAssetList = [];
  @override
  initState() {
    foundAssetList = assetList;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = assetList;
    } else {
      results = assetList
          .where((user) =>
          user["name"].toLowerCase().contains(
              enteredKeyword.toLowerCase().toList();
          }
              setState(() {
      foundAssetList = results;
      });
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey I think the best thing to do is a stream builder that listents to the input of your Textfield. It will update automatically after the user makes a change.

Comment: How would that work in relation to the code above? Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few things:

1. You need a state that keeps track of the text in the `TextField` - you can do this by adding a state variable and use `onChanged` of the `TextField` to update the variable
2. Write a function that returns a list of the cryptocurrencies based on the keyword: You can create a function that returns the list of all cryptocurrencies if the keyword is empty, else return a filtered list
3. Replace the `assetList` variable in the `ListView.builder` with the `filteredList` (should be the value of the function in step 2)

The result code should look like this (put this in `_AddCryptoAssetScreenState`:

```dart
 String _keyword = "";
  
  List<Asset> _getFilteredList() {
    if (_keyword.isEmpty) {
      return assetList;
    }
    return assetList
          .where((user) =>
          user.name.toLowerCase().contains(
              _keyword.toLowerCase())).toList();
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final filteredList = _getFilteredList();
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        builder: (_, controller) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(),
                  child: TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only()),
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      setState(() {
                        _keyword = text;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: filteredList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return AssetCryptoCard(
                        name: filteredList[index].name,
                        image: filteredList[index].image,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried and got this error: A value of type 'List<Asset>' can't be returned from the method '_getFilteredList' because it has a return type of 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'.

Comment: And in the ListView.builder. I got this error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: Oh @YSC , that's because I only assumed that the bottom most part of your code is correct. I checked further and the return type should be `List<Asset>` instead. And instead of `user["name"]` I would replace that with `user.name`

Answer (score 0):

Use the textfoemfield onChanged property

```
TextFormField(
 OnChanged: (value){
  _runFilter(value);
 }
);
```

Or

For API request use future feature in [textfield_search](https://pub.dev/packages/textfield_search) package

please review this package can provide solution with different approach

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. But before applying onChanged. There is an error with regard to my last code (shown above).

A value of type 'List<Asset>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'.